# Is it possible to filter out dirty data before it gets into the pivot table in excel automatially?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, pivot-table

I have a database that has got dirty data.
For example, the No. of days should be an integer, however people fill in doubles like 2.3 or 5.2...
My pivot table sample data from this database.

The workflow (which is unchangeable) is:

1. Export data in a .csv from different divisions, which has got dirty data in it.
2. upload all .csv to the server
3. use the query to read all .csv into one big excel, therefore dirty data gets into the big excel file.
4. use a pivot table in another excel to analyze.

**What I need is to make my pivot table automatically ignore these dirty data in the data source.**
Basically to ignore those 2.3 days or 5.2 days.
So when I calculate total days in the pivot table, I get only integer numbers.

I cannot clean up the database cause,

- it's an export from an online data collector
- too much data and too many types of dirty. Int -> double, empty fields, mis-spellings, etc.
- luckily those types of dirty have a pattern, therefore maybe I can
  filter them out before they get into the pivot table

Apr. 21 edit
The Power Query seems promising. Will take a look at that.
Big thanks to the SuperUser community and you guys for the feedback!

*For those who might be asking, input 2 Spaces at the end of a sentence then press Enter will give you a new line, instead of a new paragraph.

Like this.*

Comment: The more "types of dirty", the less you can automate the cleaning. What have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Power Query might be able to help you clean up the data prior to placing in a table. Between adding custom columns and then filtering based on them, you can probably get where you want to go. An example for truncating those doubles down to integers in Power Query can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=799-PVYA-C4). Depending on how exactly you need to filter, you might be able to get by without Power Query too if you're able to add columns to the raw dirty data, and then filter from that dirty data and use the filtered data in the Pivot Table.

Comment: @Enzo Luo ,,, you have three options 1. convert those dirty data days into integer 2. use INDEX & MATCH to separate them 3. FILTER then DELETE !!

Comment: Power Query can help you filter data before you create the Pivottable.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter for integers like so:

```
=FILTER(A1:B5, IF( ISNUMBER(B1:B5), MOD(B1:B5,1), 1) = 0)
```

It checks the type of an entry to be a valid number, then if so, does the `MOD()` using 1, so any integer will return 0. That will return TRUE in the test for each cell in the range. If it fails the `ISNUMBER()` test, "1" is returned. Doesn't matter it's an integer as it is not tested for being one, just that it equals zero or doesn't (it doesn't, of course) and so returning a FALSE to the test `FILTER()` is performing over the range.

You can then use this as an input to further `FILTER()` functions wrapping it, though you have to remember that your test must always be over the entire original set of rows, though the column can change with each wrap function:  never try to run the test only over the current result's data set... always over the entire row set first used.

You might then be able to gradually work out the worst data, then get progressively deeper in the cleaning as time passes and you have time to do it or ideas about how to characterize things to clean more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my solution!
Power Query is the right way to go guys!
If you get dirty data in your pivot table when pulling data from a database, don't even think about how to deal with the dirty data in your pivot table. Go straight up to the database, and clean or exclude dirty data there, right in the database.
The right approach is always to make sure that the dirty data does not get into the database, not find a way to deal with dirty data when processing!